# Creating objects from another layer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to develop an application for my final year project. Currently I have the presentation layer where I have the UI stuff like forms. Now I've went ahead and added class library to the project and added a class Employee in the new project.

Now When I try to make an object

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
```

c# returns an error saying i'm missing some names space or type etc :((

How can this be solved?

Comment: Could you post the error message from the compiler to your question perhaps?

Comment: Did you miss the `Using` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have added a reference to the *class library* in your *presentation layer*'s project. Then try to import the `namespace` which contains the `Employee` class in your code file as the following:

```
using EmployeeClassNameSpace;
```

You can also use the fully qualified name of the `Employee` type as the following:

```
EmployeeClassNameSpace.Employee = new EmployeeClassNameSpace.Employee();
```

---

Refer to the following

[namespace (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[using Directive (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Comment: Answer is discripting and easy to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the new project from your UI project, to do this, right click your UI project and choose add reference, then go to the projects tab and choose your class library project.

Also you should add a using directive to the code-file that is trying to instantiate Employee, in case the namespaces differ.

Comment: @Oded: I don't see a mention of that anywhere in his post, he just said he added a "class library to the project", which I interpreted maybe he confused project with solution.

Comment: Yep correct, I have a solution with UI layer later I added a new project a class library to use it as business layer. Layer created a class and tried to create a object from that class in UI layer which didn't work. After importing the BusinessLayer as "using BusinessLayer" IDE recognized empoloyee :)

Answer (score 1):

Your UI class that has this code need to add a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) importing the class library namespace to this code file.

Either that, or use the fully qualified name of the type.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer.